# CSS Hover Events, How to Trigger a Parent's Effect

Tags: html, css, events, hover, anchor

I have a dropdown menu `<ul/>` which displays a second list `<ul/>` when hovered on.

Hence:

```
<ul id="NavBar">
    <li><a href="#">News & Press Releases</a>
        <ul class="NavBar_drop">
            <li><a href="#">OCPO Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ocean County Government</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When you hover on the "News & Press Releases" anchor tag, the following effect takes place:

```
#NavBar > li > a:hover {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));
    color: #000;
}
```

However, the second you move to any of the child links, such as "OCPO Home", the effect of the above hover disappears. Obviously I would have to force it to stay using another CSS tag, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is my attempt:

```
.NavBar_drop:hover #NavBar > li > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: When you move to the child links you are moving OFF the `<a>`; hence the hover effect stopping. Try changing the selector so that it's triggered when you hover on the parent `<li>` instead: #NavBar > li: hover { CSS Styles here... }

Comment: That'll do it! Thank you. I thought it would go through the anchor tag, not the list item, but now that makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome; I'll make this an answer instead so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you *can't* trigger an effect on a parent element. However, you don't actually need to do that given the problem you've stated. When you move to the child links you are moving OFF the `<a>`; hence the hover effect stopping. Change the selector so that it's triggered when you hover on the parent `<li>` instead:

```
#NavBar > li:hover { 
    /* CSS Styles here... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Dre's answer, if you just want to highlight your `<a>` when over the entire `<li>`, try using this css rule instead:

```
#NavBar > li:hover > a {
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/278ed)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select parent element in cascading style sheets so what you are trying is not possible

Comment: There may be something wrong with the way I'm going about it, but it is certainly not impossible.